# How to set materialize multiselect selected values from jquery

Tags: materialize

I want to set values as selected at initial loading of my page but I'm not able to set them.

Here is my HTML markup:

```
<select multiple id="access_rights">
 <option value="default" disabled selected>Choose your options</option>
 <option value="create">Create</option> 
 <option value="read">Read</option> 
 <option value="update">Update</option> 
 <option value="delete">Delete</option> 
</select> <label>Select Access Rights</label>`
```

Now I want 'Create' and 'Update' as default selected at first loading of page.

How can I do that?

Comment: add attribute selected in <option> ...as you are doing for first option (Choose your options)

Answer (score 4):

See Working Demo :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select').material_select();
});


var selectedOptions=[
  "create",
  "update"
];

$.each(selectedOptions, function(i,e){
    $("#access_rights option[value='" + e + "']").prop("selected", true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">

 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
 

<label for="access_rights">Select Access Rights</label>
<select id="access_rights" multiple>  
  <option value="default" disabled>Choose your options</option>        <option value="create">Create</option>                     <option value="read">Read</option>                         <option value="update">Update</option>                     <option value="delete">Delete</option>                 </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use selected in create and update option. For Ex:-

```
<select multiple id="access_rights">                                               
   <option value="default" disabled>Choose your options</option>                                                  
   <option value="create" selected>Create</option>                                                  
   <option value="read">Read</option>                                                  
   <option value="update" selected>Update</option>                                                  
   <option value="delete">Delete</option>                                              </select>
<label>Select Access Rights</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    $( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".select-wrapper").each(function() {
      var wrapper = this;
      $(this).find("ul>li").each(function() {
          var li = this;
          var option_text = $(this).text();

          $(wrapper).find("select option:selected").each(function() {
             var selected_text = $(this).text();

             if(option_text == selected_text) {
                //$(li).addClass("active selected");
                //$(li).find("input").prop('checked', true);
                $(li).click();
             }
          });
      });
    });
    });
```

Comment: Adding some description may add value to your answer.